# Fast check how many elements of a list are contained in another list in R

Tags: r, list, comparison, match

Given two lists of character elements:

```r
set.seed(0)  

indexes <- list(c("1","2","3"),c("2","3","4"))
> indexes
[[1]]
 [1] "1" "2" "3"

[[2]]
 [1] "2" "3" "4"

try <- list(as.character(round(rnorm(10,2,2),0)),
        as.character(round(rnorm(10,2,2),0)),
        as.character(round(rnorm(10,2,2),0)))
> try
[[1]]
 [1] "5"  "1"  "5"  "5"  "3"  "-1" "0"  "1"  "2"  "7" 

[[2]]
 [1] "4" "0" "0" "1" "1" "1" "3" "0" "3" "0"

[[3]]
 [1] "2"  "3"  "2"  "4"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "1"  "-1" "2"
```

I want to check **how many** characters of each "sublist" inside `try` are contained into **each one** of the "sublists" of `indexes` in a "pairwise comparison"-ish way.

For example: in `try[[1]]` we have that `("1","3","1","2")` are contained inside `indexes[[1]]`, so the result would be 4 for this match. Then, for the match between `try[[2]]` and `indexes[[1]]` we have `("1","1","1","3","3")` so the result wouldbe 5 here. Same reasoning for `try[[3]]` and `indexes[[1]]`.
Then we pass at the match between `try[[1]]` and `indexes[[2]]` which is represented by `("3","2")`, so the result here would be 2, and so on.
I would like the results to be stored in variables as an output (see example below)

I found a working solution to do so, but I have a massive list to apply this on (my real `try` list has 4 million elements and my `indexes` list has 100 elements), so what I'm doing is extremely slow.
Here's my solution:

```r
for(i in 1:length(indexes)){
  tmp <- lapply(try,function(x) sum(x %in% indexes[[i]]))
  assign(paste0("a",i),tmp)
}

> a1
[[1]]
 [1] 4

[[2]]
 [1] 5

[[3]]
 [1] 7

> a2
[[1]]
 [1] 2

[[2]]
 [1] 3

[[3]]
 [1] 8
```

Comment: By replacing your `for` loop with `lapply`, I get around 25% improvement. `lapply(indexes, function(ind) { lapply(try, function(x) sum(x %in% ind))})`.

Comment: Using `assign` so often is slow (and the result not convenient).

Comment: @Psidom Thanks, but this way I don't see how to assign the result to some variables in the form I specified in the question..
@Roland actually the result I get with `assign` is exactly what I'm looking for: one variable for each result. Moreover, the very slow part in my code is `lapply`.

Comment: Then you are looking for the wrong result. There is no reason whatsoever to put these results in separate variables. You should never use `assign` for this.

Comment: I want these values in separate variables so that I can then pass them in as columns inside a `data.table` with the `:=` operator: I don't see another way to do that, but that's another question.  
As regards to the speed, as I said the `assign` part is only taking a bit of time, the big problem comes from the other line of my code (and, probably, from the fact that I'm using a loop).

Comment: 1.) We have probably an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/203914) here. 2.) If you intend to put this into a data.table, do that directly using `set`. (But of course you need sufficient RAM.) No need to create variables in between. 3.) There is probably no way to avoid loops for this in pure R. 4.) The best way forward appears to be parallelization, but if you have to do 4e8 comparisons that will take a long time regardless of how you do it, but of course you need to optimize as much as possible. Don't forget to profile and benchmark potential solutions.

Comment: And of course, consider if there really is no smarter algorithm than brute force for your final objective.

Comment: Instead of two explicit loops, you might, also, check something like: `id = rep(seq_along(try), lengths(try)); utry = unlist(try, FALSE, FALSE); sapply(indexes, function(x) rowsum(as.integer(utry %in% x), id))` i.e. loop only over `indexes` to apply `match` and put hopes on `rowsum` to take over the "by each element of `try`"

Comment: I must be asleep, but how about a double loop over `intersect` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I just microbenchmarked your approach using lapply instead of loops and it takes exactly twice the time of my approach, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

If this is still too slow, you probably need to consider doing it with compiled code, e.g., using Rpcc. I don't see a way to do this with vectorized functions:

```
combs <- expand.grid(try = seq_along(try), indexes = seq_along(indexes))
combs$n_match <-  mapply(function(i, j, a, b) sum(a[[i]] %in% b[[j]]), 
       combs[,1], combs[,2], 
       MoreArgs = list(a = try, b = indexes))
#  try indexes n_match
#1   1       1       4
#2   2       1       5
#3   3       1       7
#4   1       2       2
#5   2       2       3
#6   3       2       8
```

Comment: Thank you Roland, but I think it's difficult to use your approach since my real `try` list has 4 million elements, and my `indexes` list has 100 elements. This would result in a matrix which wouldn't even fit into memory.
I should have specified that in the question, I'll edit that right away.

Comment: If your try is much larger than indexes, you probably want to put the loop through the `try` out of `indexes` to reduce the looking up time. Something like: `lapply(try, function(x) { lapply(indexes, function(ind) sum(x %in% ind))})` and also in this way the result will be stored in a list whose order corresponds to the list `try`.

Comment: The number of combinations (and thus the memory demand) is independent of how you store the results.

Comment: I said that because I would have 400million rows (4 million*100) and 3 columns. I read that each element of a `data.frame` approximately takes 8 bytes of memory (correct me if I'm wrong), so this would result in a `data.frame` of almost 9gb.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you store this in one object or several objects. The memory needed is practically the same.

Answer (score 0):

I. How many elements

```
length(try[[1]][which(try[[1]] %in% indexes[[1]])])
# [1] 7
length(try[[2]][which(try[[2]] %in% indexes[[1]])])
# [1] 3
length(try[[3]][which(try[[3]] %in% indexes[[1]])])
# [1] 6
length(try[[1]][which(try[[1]] %in% indexes[[2]])])
# [1] 5
length(try[[2]][which(try[[2]] %in% indexes[[2]])])
# [1] 4
length(try[[3]][which(try[[3]] %in% indexes[[2]])])
# [1] 5
```

II. Which elements

```
try[[1]][which(try[[1]] %in% indexes[[1]])]
# [1] "2" "1" "1" "1" "3" "1" "1"
try[[2]][which(try[[2]] %in% indexes[[1]])]
# [1] "3" "1" "2"
try[[3]][which(try[[3]] %in% indexes[[1]])]
# [1] "3" "1" "2" "3" "3" "2"
try[[1]][which(try[[1]] %in% indexes[[2]])]
# [1] "2" "3" "4" "4" "4"
try[[2]][which(try[[2]] %in% indexes[[2]])]
# [1] "3" "4" "4" "2"
try[[3]][which(try[[3]] %in% indexes[[2]])]
# [1] "3" "2" "3" "3" "2"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a compact form for this as my list `try` is huge and going through every possibility would be impossible

Comment: Oops, will check as soon as possible. Sorry and Thank you.